# Why am i getting a double value for adding integers in python?

Tags: python

I wrote this function sum_of_digits which takes n (a number) and returns the sum of its digits

```
def sum_of_digits(n):
    sum = 0
    while n > 0:
        d = n%10
        sum+=d
        n/= 10
    return sum

print(sum_of_digits(9))
```

I have no clue what is going wrong, but the last statement `print(sum_of_digits(9))` returns `10.000000000000004`, and I cant figure how to correct it. Can anyone help me?

I have already tried rephrasing the same code in many different ways, I've tried using a *for* loop, and nothing I seem to do helps the code.

Comment: There are two division operators: `/` and `//`. The latter returns integer values if both arguments are integers. Also, it may be more efficient to use `divmod`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem you taught me something new today.  I thought that `//` would always return an integer result, but it turns out it does not.

Comment: @MarkRansom I had to check as I was typing up the comment; I learned something new today too. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of division operator `/` try using floor division `//` to avoid this floating points errors.
Also, you may refer this post to understand this concept clearly.
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)